# Fatal error detected Failed to execute script

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, wxpython

He intentado generar un archivo ejecutable (.exe) a partir de un archivo python y aunque lo puedo correr sin problema en mi pc, cuando lo ejecuto en otro pc, me aparece el error descrito. A continuación doy más detalles de lo que he hecho:

He creado un programa main.py que importa wx para interfaz gráfica e importa subprograma.py que contiene a su vez matplotlib,numpy, y un archivo excel usando pandas.

Convertí main.py a exe usando los siguientes comandos:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./icono.ico main.py
```

Sin embargo cuando corro el ejecutable en otro pc me sale error.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar `scipy` para instalarlo `pip install scipy` y si quieres la consola de scipy luego de instalarlo llamalo con este codigo: `auto-py-to-exe`

Comment: ```scipy``` tiene una plataforma para su mejor manejo.